# How to play different video files as one file?

Tags: caching, video, html5-video, jwplayer, transcoding

I want to concatenate different video files (playlist) as one file, so user can play them as if they were one movie, I read about pre-buffering, but I didn't find a clear way to do so, also is it possible to just play a certain portion of a file without downloading the whole file,

Regards,

Comment: I'm not sure that you can do that with jwplayer, and will watch closely for answers, but maybe you can investigate Smooth Streaming?

Comment: I'm not concerned with JW Player in specific, even with HTML5 player, if there any available ways, please mention

Comment: Try reading this.  It's no easy-peasy, but maybe it will give you some info... http://www.iis.net/download/SmoothStreaming

Comment: I read about when you first mentioned, but it depends totally on the server side, but I need a client side way to do this, so the server is just acting as media provider

Comment: My guess is that you won't be able to seamlessly concatenate multiple files on web client.  If you do, please let me know!

Comment: Till now, I'm able to get that behavior using rtmp servers, but no clue using html5 player.